How do I install a specific version of Qt Creator?
I'm using Qt Creator 14.0.0 and finding the designer very unstable; when it crashes there is no error and the app exits.
I want to return to the latest version of Qt Creator 13.x.
It seems that the Qt Maintenance Tool does not let you pick a specific version of Qt Creator and makes you install the latest version.

Some earlier versions of Qt Creator are available here but it stops at the version 10. Versions 11 and above are available here

@Pamputt Yeah, I have been there before and didn't find it useful. The GitHub project seems to be a much better resource. https://github.com/qt-creator/qt-creator/releases?q=v13&expanded=true

Qt publishes Qt Creator packages on their Qt Creator GitHub project.
For example, you can search for v13. I tested the .deb and it works well. I installed it with:
sudo apt install ./qtcreator-linux-x64-13.0.2.deb
For me, this installed Qt Creator to:
/opt/qt-creator/bin/qtcreator
This seems to be a faster and more straightforward way than using the Qt Maintenance Tool.
